# Extracting data of certain category from string (python)

Tags: python

I have an example string:
`'Last year's Fortune rank: No.3 2016 revenue $215.6 billion One-year Revenue Change: -7.7%'`

I want to extract particular informations from such strings to put them in python DataFrame under certain cateories such as:

`Last year's Fortune rank: 3
2016 revenue ($B): 215.6
One-year revenue change: -7.7%`

Is there a way to search for certain text in string and return the next word after where it was found?

Comment: You can try using regex

Comment: will all the text be in the same format?

Comment: @Kalyan yes, all strings are build the same way, the only thing that changes are the particular values indicating rank, revenue etc.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
s = "Last year's Fortune rank: No.3 2016 revenue $215.6 billion One-year Revenue Change: -7.7%"

import re
expression = re.compile(r"Last year's Fortune rank: No.(?P<rank>\d+) +2016 revenue \$(?P<revenue>[.0-9]+) billion One-year Revenue Change: (?P<revchange>[-.0-9]+)%")

m = expression.match(s)
print(m.groupdict())
```

Which outputs:

```
{'rank': '3', 'revenue': '215.6', 'revchange': '-7.7'}
```

And of course, you can do whatever you like with the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This is not very clean but it gets the job done:

```
s = 'Last year''s Fortune rank: No.3 2016 revenue $215.6 billion One-year Revenue Change: -7.7%'
print('Last year''s Fortune rank:', s.split('No.')[1].split()[0])
print('2016 revenue ($B):', s.split('$')[1].split()[0])
print('One-year revenue change:', s.split(':')[-1])
```

Output:

```
Last years Fortune rank: 3
2016 revenue ($B): 215.6
One-year revenue change:  -7.7%
```